# didn’t know that making promises is haram

Tags: halal-haram, dua

i think i may have made a promise to Allah (swt) a while ago while making dua when i said (in my head) that, when i get older, i’ll eventually stop doing a couple of things that i thought were haram. i didn’t know that making promises is haram at the time and the idea that i was promising something honestly didn’t even cross my mind. i clearly didn’t think it through and i now regret it.

i have also since then learned that those things that i thought were haram are actually permissible and now i don’t have any desire to leave them.

i’ve already broken this “promise” so what should i do next? should i just repent and not worry about keeping it anymore? did it even count as a promise? i know i’m overthinking this but i just don’t want to upset Allah (swt).

Answer (score 1):

If you made a promise but not in the name of Allah then all you need to do is repent. If you included giving a promise to Allah like this for example “I promise Allah not to return to this sin again”, then you would need to repent and expiate for breaking an oath. The expiation for breaking an oath is to to feed ten people, clothe them or free a slave. If you are not able to do any of this then you should fast three days. Allah knows best.

https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/102811/no-wrong-in-entrusting-a-charitable-society-with-paying-the-expiation-for-breaking-an-oath